# What are 'factors' in biology?

Tags: terminology

My question is what does the word 'factor' mean in words like transcription-factor or nerve growth-factor? What is similar between these different compounds such that they deserve the word 'factor' in their name?

Edit: My confusion comes perhaps from the use of the word 'factor' in statistics, where it refers to a variable that can take on discrete values (e.g., the factor Gender takes on values 'male' and 'female'). Here a different meaning of the word seems to be used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is poorly researched. https://www.google.se/search?q=transcription-factor&oq=transcription-factor&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @rg255 - I think it is fine - your (Swedish :-) google result links to transcription factor. This question doesn't ask what a TF does, it asks for the broader interpretation of 'factor'.

Comment: I'd still suggests its poorly researched (https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=biological%20factors) if the OP has done research and asked about what thye specifically don't grasp it would be on topic

Comment: @rg255 - you may be right. I'd say it's borderline. The voting system will tell :)

Comment: this is googling-based question. I strongly feel this type of questions should not be dignified with an answer. Otherwise bar is pretty low

Comment: @AliceD do you think it is OK to create a question for every entry from a [dictionary](http://www.phschool.com/science/biology_place/glossary/)?

Comment: I agree this is off topic. There is no special meaning of the word factor here, a dictionary could answer this question (and did). This is about English language usage.

Comment: Yeah you guys are right. Vote2close2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of poorly researched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many meanings of "factor" in Biology. In the context where you place it, namely **bio-active substances, such as hormones and enzymes** I would go for the definition given by the [Medical Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Biological+factors):

> ***factor*** [fak´ter] :
>   an agent or element that contributes to the production of a result.

Within this definition, a transcription factor contributes to the transcription of DNA into mRNA, and nerve growth factor contributes to the growth and survival of neurons.